# How to specify rules only for specific browsers with Compass css

Tags: css, sass, compass

I'm using Compass in my CSS and I am trying to specify part of my Sass Css to be run only in Chrome. I tried `@include with-prefix` but it dosen't seem to work. Is there anyway to run these specific animations only for specific browsers, in this case chrome?

```
@include with-prefix(-webkit) {
            .slideFromRight {

                &.ng-enter {
                    @include animation(slideFromRight ease $animationSpeed);
                    @include animation-iteration-count(1);
                    @include transform-origin(0 0);
                    @include animation-fill-mode(forwards);
                }

                &.ng-leave {
                    position: fixed;
                    @include animation(slideToLeft ease $animationSpeed);
                    @include animation-iteration-count(1);
                    @include transform-origin(0 0);
                    @include animation-fill-mode(forwards);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Not possible. CSS (let alone Compass) won't know what the browser is. The only way to do this, is to use specific CSS that is only supported by the browser you want to target. If the CSS you want is supported by every browser, you cannot block it in some of them using CSS alone.

Comment: Given the number of non-webkit browsers that support properties with the webkit prefix, I don't believe that your desired output is going to work the way you think it will.  http://www.brucelawson.co.uk/2014/on-internet-explorer-supporting-webkit-vendor-prefixes/